# MPlayer audio channel (left/right) switching

Tags: audio, media-player, audio-streaming, mplayer

I'm trying to make an application, media player using mplayer slave mode.
Any clue about switching VCD Karaoke channel (left and right) on the fly, while
the video is playing on the mplayer-slave mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

switching audio track with

LEFT `echo "af pan=2:1:1:0:0" > slave_fifo_file`

RIGHT `echo "af pan=2:0:0:1:1" > slave_fifo_file`

Answer (score 0):

I also hard to find this solution and finally found that

```
af_add pan=2:1:1:0:0

af_add pan=2:0:0:1:1
```

is working for changing audio channel Left to Right for VCD karaoke channels.
I hope this will help you developing your Karaoke software.

I developed basic music player using mplayer and VB.NET. If you are interested please tell me.